# Help me understand SpeedFan settings

Tags: windows, fan, speedfan

My computer fans speed up and down whenever my cpu use twitches. The varying sound of the fans is very annoying so I installed [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to try to fix this.

I have fiddled with the SpeedFan settings but can't get them to work well.

Either it's just like before or it doesn't speed up the fan enough.

My first question is.

What is the difference between these settings (For PWM mode).

- SmartFan 3
- SmartFan 4
- Thermal Cruise
- Fan Speed Cruise
- Manual

Comment: The title is a bit vague

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thermal Cruise**

Smart Fan system which can control the fan speed automatically depending on current **temperature** to keep it within a specific range.

**Fan Speed Cruise**

Smart Fan system which can control the fan speed automatically depending on current fan **speed** to keep it within a specific range

**Manual Control Mode**

Smart Fan control system can be disabled and the fan speed control algorithm can be programmed by
BIOS or application software.

**Smart Fan**

It's a noise restrained system to automatically increase the fan speed when CPU operating loading is high. After the CPU is in normal operating condition, the system will lower the fan speed for a silent operating environment.